# How to install python module(s) via pip using salt?

Tags: python, saltstack, pip

I need to install the `paramiko` module of python on multiple machines using the salt stack.

I looked at the documentation about how to do this, but was not able to understand the syntax.

Can someone please explain me line-by-line what happens in the following snippet:

```
python-pip:
  pkg.installed

virtualenvwrapper:
  pip.installed:
    - require:
      - pkg: python-pip
```

Also, can you add an example snippet for a recipe installing multiple python modules via pip using salt?

Answer (score 2):

```
python-pip: # The name of the package this state installs, this must be unique in your salt states
  pkg.installed # The state (pkg) and action (installed)

virtualenvwrapper: # The name of the package
  pip.installed: # The state (pip) and action (installed)
    - require: # Require means only install this if the following is already installed
      - pkg: python-pip # pkg python-pip which is mentioned earlier
```

Another way to write the first part:

```
instaled python pip:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: python-pip
```

If you wanted to install multiple packages:

```
installed python pip, paramiko and complete:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs: 
      - python-pip
      - python-complete
      - python-paramiko
```

Alternatively, paramiko is in pip:

```
 paramiko:
   pip.installed
```

Also, to install multiple things from pip:

```
 install lots from pip:
   pip.installed:
     - names:
       - paramiko
       - boto3
       - pycurl
```

Remember, the [docs](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.pkg.html#salt.states.pkg.installed) are your friend, but they are not exhaustive, #salt on freenode irc is also a great place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

First first block is installing the package `python-pip` via your distro's package manager like `yum` or `apt-get`

The second block is install `virtualenvwrapper` via pip like `pip install virtualenvwrapper` but its also saying in order to run that command you need to have the package `python-pip` installed